# self.view not within visible coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm going through someone's code trying to determine why their storyboard goes out of control on orientation flips..

Modal segues are going from View Controller to another View Controller. The segue identifier is being defined and called correctly:

```
self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifiername" sender:self];
```

if the orientation is standard.. self.view.frame.origin.x and y are 0,0.  If you flip it to landscape..  you get -20, 1280?  Nothing is defined programmaticly using CGRects and all standard Orientations return true with no changes.

Does anyone have any ideas whatsoever???

Comment: How (NSLog()?) and from where(what method) are you getting the frame origins?

Comment: when the view controller is called, checking the origin from the viewdidload method.  NSLog of self.view.frame.origin.x = -20 and -1280 when in landscape. standard portrait is 0, 0.  Update is something ridiculous also..

Answer (score 0):

I would look through the project for any odd calls to `setFrame:` obviously. But also, for `self.view.transform =`, applied transforms (like zooming with a transform) affect frame.  You can also check your bounds, I suspect the bounds of your view are correct, but checking never hurts.

Also you can easily log a `CGRect` like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
```

Good hunting.

Comment: Unfortunately most of this was done in the IB on the storyboard.  The coding is actually pretty miniscule.  Just going to recreate the elements in the IB step by step and see where the problem comes from.  Talk about a headache...